# Pygame dibujo masivo de puntos

Tags: python, python-2.7, hilos, pygame

Hay una función que tiene un array de características para ser graficadas en la pantalla con pygame es decir coordenadas, colores y diametros, con threading quiero graficarlas de manera simultanea todos los círculos al mismo tiempo. Con un ciclo for leo el array y lo grafico pero en vez de graficarlos todos, son graficados uno por uno.

```py
def circulos():
    puntos = [{'posicion': 700, 'color': (0, 0, 255), 'posy': 300}, {'posicion': 
    100, 'color': (255, 0, 0), 'posy': 200}, {'posicion': 100, 'color': (255, 0, 
    0), 'posy': 100}, {'posicion': 700, 'color': (0, 0, 255), 'posy': 0}]
    speed = 1
    posy = 0
    print puntos
    black=(0,0,0)
    for x in puntos:
        posx = x["posicion"]
        color = x["color"]
        posy = x["posy"] 
        posy = posy + speed
        x["posy"] = posy
        pygame.draw.circle(surface,color,(posx,x["posy"]), 10,0)
        pygame.display.update()
        surface.fill(black)`

    hilo=threading.Thread(target=circulo)
    hilo.start()
```

Lo que tambien se necesita es mostrar un desplazamiento de caída para ello se hace un incremento en la posicion vertical y se sobreescribe despues de ser graficado el circulo

Answer (score 0):

Primero, **PyGame no es thread-safe, nunca debes dibujar desde un hilo hijo directamente**, esto solo se puede hacer desde el hilo principal de forma segura. Esto es algo bastante común en muchos frameworks gráficos basados en un mainloop encargado de manejar eventos.

Esto no significa que no podamos crear contenido desde un hilo o proceso hijo, lo que significa es que el blitting y dibujado de la pantalla solo lo puede hacer el hilo principal.

En cuanto a que se grafican en serie, que uses un hilo es indiferente, lo relevante es que realmente creas cada punto y lo dibujas en la surface en una iteración de un ciclo `for`, por lo que lógicamente se van dibujando uno detrás de otro, uno por cada iteración del `for`. El truco es actualizar solo cuando todos los puntos estén dibujados en la surface.

Si quieres usar un hilo, una forma segura es crear una surface en el hilo y una vez completa con todos los puntos dibujados, usar un evento para comunicarse con el mainloop del hilo principal, el cual es el que debe encargarse del blitting de la misma y de actualizar la pantalla.

Un ejemplo con 1000 puntos de color, posición y velocidad aleatoria:

```
import random
import sys
import threading

import pygame


WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 650
FPS = 60


def circulos(draw_circles_event):
    circulos = [{'x': random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH),
                 'y': random.randint(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT),
                 'color': (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)),
                 'vel': random.randint(1, 5)}
                 for _ in range(1000)
                ]

    black = (0, 0, 0)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while draw_circles_event.is_set():
        surface = pygame.Surface((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ))
        for circulo in circulos:
            posx = circulo["x"]
            color = circulo["color"]
            posy = circulo["y"] 
            posy += circulo["vel"]
            if posy > WINDOW_HEIGHT:
                posy = 0
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, (posx, posy), 10, 0)
            circulo["y"] = posy

        event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT + 1,
                                   {"bitmap": surface}
                                   )
        pygame.event.post(event)
        clock.tick_busy_loop(FPS)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Circles Down")
    window  = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT),
                                    pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF
                                    )

    draw_circles_event = threading.Event()
    draw_circles_event.set()
    hilo = threading.Thread(target=circulos, args=(draw_circles_event, ), daemon=True)
    hilo.start()


    circles_surface = None

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # mainloop
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1:
                circles_surface = event.bitmap

        if circles_surface is not None:
            window.blit(circles_surface, (0, 0))

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick_busy_loop(FPS)

    draw_circles_event.clear()
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```